# How much should I care in my JS scripts for IE 8 and blew?

Tags: javascript, css

how much should I care about IE 8 and blew in ( JS and CSS ) code ?

Comment: As much as the number of users you have that use IE8. Kahn Academy just dropped support for IE8 since they only saw 1.2% of people using it (I don't know how many visitors they have though).

Comment: It depends ... basically, this isn't place to decide this for there is no generic rule other than checking your project's audience.

Comment: If you believe [*NetMarketShare*](https://www.netmarketshare.com/browser-market-share.aspx?qprid=2&qpcustomd=0) for June 2014, IE 8 is over 20% of the desktop user share (larger than any other browser). Is that enough to care about? Other stats for balance: [*W3Counter*](http://www.w3counter.com/globalstats.php) (nothing to do with the W3C).

Answer (score 1):

That completely depends.

If you have the luxury of good data (i.e. Google Analytics), see what the browser breakdown is for your users.  Are they mostly using newer browsers?  What percentage of your users are using IE8 and below?  I typically try to support any browser with ~2-5% usage, but that percentage is 100% up to you.

If you don't have good data, try to think about your users.  Are they primarily at work in a corporate environment where they're forced to use old browsers?  Are they young college students who will mostly be using Chrome anyway?  Get in the mind of your users and try to deduce what would be best.

**Ultimately, though, it comes down to an economic decision.**  What is the cost of supporting IE8 and below for you?  Is it an extra week of work?  Is it introducing technical debt?  Is adding polyfills going to make your website slower?  Does supporting old browsers mean you can't implement new and exciting features?  You need to weigh those costs with the benefit you'll gain from supporting older browsers.

This is a completely subjective question, and it completely depends on your requirements and users.

Comment: Bottom line: `This is a completely subjective question`, hence it's closed. ;-)